# When is the fragment identifier (or hash mark) in a URL processed by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, fragment-identifier

When a browser is loading a page with a fragment identifier (#, or hash mark), at what point in the page load is it processed?

Is there an event I can listen for and intercept with JS?